# Update Database After Editing Form Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have asked many questions related to this, but still have not found a good answer. I get a lot of suggestions and questions, but I am not very good with Javascript or Ajax, so I need your help and not just suggestions.

I have a table that is populated with data from a database. It has a few buttons...add row, save table, edit, and deactivate. It would be nice to have the database update after each button is pressed, but for now, all i really need is for everything to update once the Save Table button is pressed. How can I get this to happen. I know I need to use Ajax, but unsure of how. If someone would be able to take some times and post an answer that would be awesome! I've been working on this for a while and could really go for figuring this out finally.

DB connection:

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxx";

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stage_Rebate_Master ORDER BY MR_ID ASC";
?>
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_name" id="mr_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>

    <input type="button" class="create-user" value="Add Row">
    <input type="submit" value="Save Table" class="save">

</table>
</div>

    <input type="button" class="create-user" value="Add Row">
    <input type="submit" value="Save Table" class="save">
```

Javascript:

```
// ----- Deactivate/Activate Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .deactivate", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
  var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

  // ------ Confirmation box in order to deactivate/activate row -----
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
    $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
    $this.val(function (i, t) {
      return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
    });
  }
});

// ----- Edit Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
    tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    // changed from here.......
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      // changed from here....... to here
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation -----
      switch (type) {
        case "buyer_id":
          if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_n":
          if (value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_e":
          if (value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_p":
          if (value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";
          }
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});

// ----- Dialog Box -----

$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      phoneRegex = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

   function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Buyer ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );

      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val() );
        });
        $tr.find('.mr_id').html( $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).length + 1 );
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Row": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );


// ----- Save Table -----
$(document).on("click", ".save", function () {

  // ------ Confirmation box in order to deactivate/activate row -----
  if (confirm('Saving will update the entire table. Are you sure you want to save?')) {
  var tabledata=[];
  $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).each(function( index ) {
      tabledata[index] = {
          mr_id: $( this ).find("td.mr_id").text(),
          mr_name: $( this ).find("td.mr_name").text(),
          buyer_id: $( this ).find("td.buyer_id").text(),
          poc_n: $( this ).find("td.poc_n").text(),
          poc_e: $( this ).find("td.poc_e").text(),
          poc_p: $( this ).find("td.poc_p").text()
      };

});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a PHP file to handle the post from AJAX, receive the data and insert or update into the database.  I assume you can handle the PHP portion.  As for the AJAX, you just need to collect your data into an object and POST it to the server.

```
var postData = {};  //Object to hold your post variables.
postData.id = 2;
postData.name = "Roger";
postData.anythingElse = "Another string";
//And so on.
$.ajax({
    url: "yourPHPfile.php",
    type: "post",
    data: postData,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

In the `yourPHPfile.php` file, you will recieve those variables with POST.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$anythingElse = $_POST['anythingElse'];
```

Comment: okay so for the "whatever you'd like" is that just any sort of random name i choose or is that need to be specific to something?? Also, i assume this is going in my javascript code page correct?

Comment: See my edit.  You can have as many fields in your postData object as you need.  And yes, this AJAX function will go in your JS code at the point where you need to send the data to the server.  Presumably in your on click handler of your save button after the confirmation.

Comment: I would also suggest looking into the DataTables plugin for jQuery.  It will make your life in displaying, changing, and saving tables of data much easier.

Comment: Would I need to put some sort of class in as the value or the postData? I can't hardcode it because I would have no idea what the table would be edited to.

Comment: You can just use your entire tabledata array you've created in your code already. Instead of implicity applying objects to the postData variable, use the serialize function to do it for you. `var postData = $.serialize(tabledata);`

Comment: What part are you not understanding?

Comment: confused with a lot of the postData stuff and most of it in general...this isn't something i have grasped too well and i just need to get it done quickly, which i haven't been able to do unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can give you that will help you understand.  This is just basic HTTP post requests and PHP code, nothing special happening here.  The postData object holds whatever data you want to send to the server, and PHP deciphers that data to which you can do with what you want.  If you get stuck at a certain point I can help, but I can't do it for you.

Comment: How does the var postData object know what I did and did not edit or change?

Comment: That is just a variable...  you need to store what you want in it.

Comment: Sorry, i knew that...i mean the actual postData object....not the variable

Comment: Just look into the DataTables plugin.  It will basically do all of this for you and guide your through the setup.  I don't know what else to say here to help you.