# Writing HTML Table Edits to Database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, dynamic

I have an HTML table that can be edited and saved. When saved I want it to update any changes made, to the database. Right now I have it so that whenever the table is saved, it automatically saves "23" into the "Buyer_ID" column because it is hardcoded in. However, how can I get it so that it is not hardcoded in and will read and save any values that are typed, added, or edited in the table?

HTML/PHP code:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_name" id="mr_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<form method="post" action="ajaxsubmit.php"> 
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" name="field" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>

    <input type="button" class="create-user" value="Add Row">
    <input type="submit" value="Save Table" class="save">

</table>
</div>

    <input type="button" class="create-user" value="Add Row">
    <input type="submit" value="Save Table" class="save">
</form>
```

JavaScript save function:

```
// ----- Save Table -----
$(document).on("click", ".save", function () {

  // ------ Confirmation box in order to deactivate/activate row -----
  if (confirm('Saving will update the entire table. Are you sure you want to save?')) {
  var tabledata=[];
  $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).each(function( index ) {
      tabledata[index] = {
          mr_id: $( this ).find("td.mr_id").text(),
          mr_name: $( this ).find("td.mr_name").text(),
          buyer_id: $( this ).find("td.buyer_id").text(),
          poc_n: $( this ).find("td.poc_n").text(),
          poc_e: $( this ).find("td.poc_e").text(),
          poc_p: $( this ).find("td.poc_p").text()
      };

});
}
});
```

Ajax submit code:

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxx";

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

try {
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $qry=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (Buyer_ID) VALUES (23)');

    $qry->execute(Array("23" => $field));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . " file: " . $e->getFile() . " line: " . $e->getLine();
    exit;
}
?>
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="field" value="<?php print $field; ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="youraction" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: `$var = $_POST['var']; ... VALUES (:var)........ bindParam(':var', $var)...` it's all in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You're still having trouble with this?  Where is your AJAX code that posts to PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Database After Editing Form Using Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288433/update-database-after-editing-form-using-ajax)

Comment: Your question is a repost of ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes but still searching for an answer...

Comment: as I stated in my first comment (which seems to answer this question)  However, ajax is not my forté, so if there's anything wrong in there, I'm not the guy for this.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Yes still having trouble! Not sure if its right, but will add the extra bit that I have in my ajax submit code now

Comment: That is not AJAX.  Did you do any research into the DataTables plugin as I suggested?

Comment: Yes i did look into it a bit, but never implemented anything into my script

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of your `<form>` elements and use only AJAX.  Change your JS `on click` handler to this.

```
$(document).on("click", ".save", function () {
   if (confirm('Saving will update the entire table. Are you sure you want to save?')) {
     var tabledata=[];
     $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).each(function( index ) {
         tabledata[index] = {
             mr_id: $( this ).find("td.mr_id").text(),
             mr_name: $( this ).find("td.mr_name").text(),
             buyer_id: $( this ).find("td.buyer_id").text(),
             poc_n: $( this ).find("td.poc_n").text(),
             poc_e: $( this ).find("td.poc_e").text(),
             poc_p: $( this ).find("td.poc_p").text()
         }
      });
      $.ajax({
        url: 'yourPHPfile.php', //Change this to your PHP file
        data: {tableData: tabledata},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        error: function (request, error) {
           console.log(error);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxx";

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$tableArray = $_POST['tableData'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    //Loop through each Array object and grab each objects value for the specified database column
    foreach($tableArray as $key=>$value){

        $qry=$conn->prepare('UPDATE Stage_Rebate_Master SET `Mr_Name`=?,`Buyer_ID`=?,`Poc_n`=?,`Poc_e`=?,`Poc_p`=? WHERE `Mr_Id`=?');

        $qry->execute(Array($value->mr_name,$value->buyer_id,$value->poc_n,$value->poc_e,$value->poc_p,$value->mr_id));
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . " file: " . $e->getFile() . " line: " . $e->getLine();
    exit;
}
?>
```

This passes a JSON array of objects to PHP with the AJAX post method.  Change the column names in the `prepare` statement to match your database columns. It will update the entire database table with all the data in the HTML table once you click "confirm" in your "Save" dialog.

I suggest you do a lot more reading on PDO prepared statements as what you have currently is not even close to a prepared statement.

This is also assuming the `mr_id` column is your primary key.  If it is not, you'll need to make those changes accordingly.

Comment: the javascript for the save button is giving me trouble...when i run the program, the dialog box from the add row is displaying on the page on load...am I keeping `$(document).on("click", ".save", function () {` this line of code? I had trouble with this before and it was a bracket/parentheses issue

Comment: Yes, you're keeping that line.  The snippet of JS you have posted does have incorrect brackets and parenthesis, but without seeing the whole thing it's hard to say. I edited my portion to show exactly how that should be.

Comment: found it...you need a bracket to close off this section `tabledata[index] = {`...will try your code now!

Comment: When you say, "Change the column names in the prepare statement to match your database columns." do you mean the literal names in the `<thead>` tag or the class names in the `<tr>` tag, or the names in the `$rows ['MR_ID']` part?

Comment: Just saw you said database columns...that answers my question

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be updating the database

Comment: See my edit in the AJAX function.  I added a success callback that will log the response from PHP.

Comment: I added the success callback, ran the program, and checked the console and didn't see anything.

Comment: Ok, well add the `error` callback as i just did. Are you sure you're even executing the AJAX call?

Comment: it looks like its trying to call `yourphpfile.php` like you put in your example, but i changed it to `ajaxsubmit.php` which is my file name...how come?

Comment: If you indeed changed it to  `url: 'ajaxsubmit.php',`, then that is not possible.

Comment: argh I had a duplicate of it and didn't even see it...okay that works now....this is the error i get in the console....`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '``'. file: C:\inetpub\ftproot\Dev\ajaxsubmit.php line: 21`

Comment: FYI - my `execute` statement is line 21

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127114/discussion-between-thevalyreangroup-and-rataiczak24).